# Does anyone know a working example of 2dsphere index in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to code up a script to do basic 2dsphere index operation mentioned here
[2dsphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) using pymongo.

I could not find any example to figure it out, this is my attempt so far:

```
from pymongo import GEOSPHERE
client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=client['dbtest']
points=db['points']
points.create_index([("loc",GEOSPHERE)])
points.insert({"loc":[2 5]})
points.insert({"loc":[30,5]})
more points.insert

for doc in points.find({"loc" : {"$near": { "$geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]},"$maxDistance":20}}}):
     print doc
```

It gives the error`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: can't find special index: 2d for: { loc: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 1, 2 ] }, $maxDistance: 20 } } }`

Comment: Your attempt is working on my machine, but I've set the maxDistance to a really large number. What MongoDB version are you using? I'm using MongoDB 2.4.3.

Answer (score 11):

The [2dsphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) (pymongo.GEOSPHERE) index type only works in MongoDB 2.4 and newer. You're also going to want to use [GeoJSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#store-geojson-objects) format for your points. Finally, MongoDB's geo query operators are order sensitive, so you'll have to use [SON](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html#bson.son.SON) when using options like $maxDistance. Here's an example using [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/#op._S_near):

```
>>> c = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> points = c.dbtest.points
>>> points.ensure_index([("loc", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
u'loc_2dsphere'
>>> points.insert({'loc': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [40, 5]}})
ObjectId('51b0e508fba522160ce84c3a')
>>> for doc in points.find({"loc" : SON([("$near", { "$geometry" : SON([("type", "Point"), ("coordinates", [40, 5])])}), ("$maxDistance", 10)])}):
...     doc
... 
{u'loc': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [40, 5]}, u'_id': ObjectId('51b0e508fba522160ce84c3a')}
```

Comment: You may want to upgrade to 2.4.4. I believe that was the version I used.

Comment: But this example isn't using the 2dsphere query.

Answer (score 5):

In most recent versions I believe `$maxDistance` must be inside the `$near` operator:

```
from bson.son import SON
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()
latitude = 10
longitude = 20
max_distance = 1000 #meters    

query = {'loc': {'$near': SON([('$geometry', SON([('type', 'Point'), ('coordinates', [longitude, latitude])])), ('$maxDistance', max_distance)])}}

for doc in db.database_name.collection_name.find(query):
    print(doc)
```

Comment: with building 2dsphere index, this query filter is correct

Answer (score 1):

Given your collection is names geoid and your geojson object is named geometry...

```
import pymongo

geoid.create_index([("geometry", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
```

That should do it!