# How to create index in mongodb with pymongo

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, scrapy, 2dsphere

I use scrapy crawl data and save it to mongodb, i want to save `2dsphere` index in mongodb.

Here is my pipelines.py file with scrapy

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    global theaters
    theaters = []

    def __init__(self):
        connection = MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        self.db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = self.db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        print 'Pipelines => open_spider =>'

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        global theaters
        # get the class item name to be collection name
        self.collection = self.db[type(item).__name__.replace('_Item','')]

        if  item['theater'] not in theaters:
            print 'remove=>',item['theater']
            theaters.append(item['theater'])
            self.collection.remove({'theater': item['theater']})

        # insert the collection name that is from class object item
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        # Here is what i try to create 2dsphere index
        self.collection.create_index({"location": "2dsphere"})

        return item
```

When i use `self.collection.create_index({"location": "2dsphere"})`

It shows error `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

If i try

```
self.collection.create_index([('location', "2dsphere")], name='search_index', default_language='english')
```

There is no error any more , but my mongodb still hasn't any index under `location`.
[image]

I think i obey the GeoJson format.

Is any way to save `2dsphere` index in mongodb when i using `scrapy` ?  Or should i just save the data like the photo structure and save index by another server file (like `nodejs`)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

According to `Adam Harrison` respond, i try to change my mongodb name `location` to `geometry`

Than add code `import pymongo` in my pipelines.py file

and use `self.collection.create_index([("geometry", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])`

There is no any error but still can't find the index under `geometry`
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does anyone know a working example of 2dsphere index in pymongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908675/does-anyone-know-a-working-example-of-2dsphere-index-in-pymongo)

Comment: His question like how to use `2dsphere` index with pymongo not how to save `2dsphere` with pymongo.

Comment: Check the answer, it address how to specify `2dsphere` index.

Comment: I have used the code like his question `self.collection.create_index([("location", "2dsphere")])` and like the answer `self.collection.ensure_index([("location", "2dsphere")])` , both of them don't show any error , but my mongodb still no any index has been created.  Can't figure it out :(

Comment: Try `collection.create_index([("geometry", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])`. Taken from the ticket bro-grammer linked. See http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html for more info

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i add `import pymongo`  and change the key name `location` to `geometry` then i use `self.collection.create_index([("geometry", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])` . It stills no error information and index on my mongodb.

Comment: @AdamHarrison I look into the document , its sounds like an solution, but no working for me . Don't know why

Comment: @AdamHarrison Tahnks for your reply, i try the code and its woring.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to do a "input_processor"/"output_processor" in the file "item.py" to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was necessary to use the ItemAdapter to convert the Item parameter into a list. So I was able to query the database.

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter, adapter
import pymongo
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

collection_name = 'myCollection'
    
    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.client.close()
```

The process_item function:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
    if self.db[self.collection_name].find_one({'id':adapter['id']}) != None:
        dado = self.db[self.collection_name].find_one_and_update({'id':adapter['id']})
        ## ----> raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}") <------
        print(f"Duplicate item found: {dado!r}")
    else:
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(ItemAdapter(item).asdict())
    return item
```